# How to append the script in JSF page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

I am new to JSF. I am creating the custom component(`@facescomponent`) from java classes files and its working fine.

```
ResponseWriter control1 =  FC.getResponseWriter();
        control1.startElement("input", this);
        control1.endElement("input");
```

Here `input` element created properly in xhtml page. For this now i have to add javascript section to add some script side functionality for this input. How can i achive this?
In jsp i can see this works fine:

```
JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();
out.append(script);
```

What is the equivalent one for this in JSF. Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you asking which element to use to start and end a script? Let's ask yourself: how would you do it in plain HTML?

Comment: and btw... `JSPWriter`... sure this is correct?

Comment: Hi Baluc, Sorry for miscommunication. simply said, i want to append the script in xhtml page from java classes in jsf. How it can be achived?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, yes its worked with jsp